# Is it possible to use build user vars plugin in a Jenkins shared library?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm implementing functionality to expose the triggering user for a Jenkins pipeline to our CD system, so I've grabbed the build user vars plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-user-vars-plugin/

The way the plugin seems to work is that you wrap the code you need the variables exposed to, like so:

```
  wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
    userId = env.BUILD_USER_ID
  }
```

I tried this on a general pipeline and just echoed it out, all was well.

I then tried implementing it in our shared library so that this would happen on all calls to CD, and I'm hitting an error.

```
wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
    jobBuildUrl ="${jobBuildUrl}&USER_ID=${env.BUILD_USER_ID}"
}
```

> [2021-08-19T10:20:22.852Z] hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.company.jenkins.pipelines.BuildManager.wrap() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2) values: [[$class:BuildUser], org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@1c9a210c]

Is there any way to use this plugin code within a shared library? If so how?

I'm lead to believe not, but I thought it was worth the asking. For reference, there is this outstanding issue: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-44741

Side note, I'm trying to do this without touching everybody's pipelines themselves. If this is impossible with this plugin, I'll probably just implement my own version of it within the shared lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That plugin is hard to use and has many issues, one of them is with shared libraries.
Instead just implement it by yourself, it is relatively easy and allows you much more control over the logic of what is done, error handling and which parameters you return.
You can use something like the following:

```groovy
/**
* Get the last upstream build that triggered the current build
* @return Build object (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun) representing the upstream build
*/
@NonCPS
def getUpstreamBuild() {
   def build = currentBuild.rawBuild
   def upstreamCause
   while (upstreamCause = build.getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause)) {
       build = upstreamCause.upstreamRun
   }
   return build
}

/**
* Get the properties of the build Cause (the event that triggered the build)
* @param upstream If true (Default) return the cause properties of the last upstream job (If the build was triggered by another job or by a chain of jobs)
* @return Map representing the properties of the user that triggered the current build.
*         Contains keys: USER_NAME, USER_ID
*/
@NonCPS
def getUserCauseProperties(Boolean upstream = true) {
   def build = upstream ? getUpstreamBuild() : currentBuild.rawBuild
   def cause = build.getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause)
   if (cause) {
       return ['USER_NAME': cause.userName, 'USER_ID': cause.userId]
   }
   println "Job was not started by a user, it was ${build.getCauses()[0].shortDescription}"
   return [:]
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, would a non-elegant solution not just involve importing the plugin in the global variable source code?

Comment: I think it is possible but will require to move this code to the `src` folder for the imports to work which will complicate the structure and the usage.

Comment: Going to mark this as an answer, since you came to similar conclusions as me and if there wasn't one saying this I was going to post one. I did it slightly differently to you and did it without NonCPS (not sure if I need that or not), but in my case I only went one level up, so I might try with yours to recurse. Thanks!

Comment: Always use the `NonCPS` annotation when you are handling un-serializable classes like (cause), else you may get serialization issues when using this function in a pipeline. See more info [Here](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/01/pipeline-scalability-best-practice/)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know cause wasn't serializable, but that makes sense. I will say I tried it without and it did work successfully, but on your advice I'll add it. I know it means the pipeline won't survive a restart and I read something else that said not to use it unless you had to. But I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was also not able to use wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) into groovy method. Therefore I think I found alternative way which seems to do the trick. You may get the username and userid (which might return email, depends on your setup) by just the following:

```
def build = currentBuild.rawBuild

def cause = build.getCause(hudson.model.Cause.UserIdCause.class)

def userName = cause.getUserName() // or use getUserId()
```