# Jenkins trigger started by user or cron

Tags: jenkins, triggers

In Jenkins, I want to differentiate between a job that was started by a user or a cron defined by me.

I tried using the:

```
is_run_by_user = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause)
```

but still it doesn't work.

Are there other expressions perhaps?

Comment: Are you using a declarative or scripted pipeline?

Comment: I am using declarative pipeline

Answer (score 2):

In declarative pipelines you can use the [Built-in Conditions](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#built-in-conditions) of the [when](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) directive to determine information about what or who triggered the build. In your case you can use the `triggeredBy` option to create your execution condition. Here is an example:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Timer Trigger') {
            when { 
                triggeredBy 'TimerTrigger' 
            }
            steps {
                echo "Running because triggered by a Timer Trigger (Cron)"
            }
        }
        stage('User Trigger') {
            when { 
                triggeredBy cause: "UserIdCause"
            }
            steps {
                echo "Running because triggered by a user"
            }
        }
        stage('Specific User Trigger') {
            when { 
                triggeredBy cause: "UserIdCause", detail: "eldarm" 
            }
            steps {
                echo "Running because triggered by eldarm"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use the build in mechanism you can extract the information yourself using scripted pipeline syntax (use inside a `script` block in declarative pipelines).
Something like:

```groovy
// First find the upstream triggered job
def build = currentBuild.rawBuild
def upstreamCause
while (upstreamCause = build.getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause)) {
    build = upstreamCause.upstreamRun
}

// Check if job was triggered by a user
def userIdCause = build.getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause)
if(userIdCause) {
   // build was triggered by a user
   def user = userIdCause.userName
   ...
}
```

See more info in the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68848294/is-it-possible-to-use-build-user-vars-plugin-in-a-jenkins-shared-library/68850571)